# How to make an array of Objects

Tags: solidity, blockchain, javascript

I need to make sth like that in solidity so I can push , edit or delete any of the elements later.
I want to push lots of todos in an array and edit them or delete by their id.

```
struct todo{
      id;
      text;
      isCompleted;
    }

todo[] todos;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Mapping](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/v0.8.7/types.html#mapping-types) in solidity .

Comment: my question is how to get all of them
in mapping I need an index to get the item. I need to get all of items like that
[
{id , name , email},
{id , name , email},
{id , name , email},
......
]